# My footer wont stay fixed - Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, sticky-footer

I am doing a lot of modifications on a wordpress theme for a friend. I have having a lot of issues with the footer staying at the bottom of the page, instead of keeps on moving up and leaving whitespace.

URL:
http://design.jarethmusic.com/about/

HTML (footer.php)

```
<?php global $woo_options; ?>
    <?php
        $total = 4;
        if ( isset( $woo_options['woo_footer_sidebars'] ) ) { $total = $woo_options['woo_footer_sidebars']; }
        if ( ( woo_active_sidebar( 'footer-1' ) ||
               woo_active_sidebar( 'footer-2' ) ||
               woo_active_sidebar( 'footer-3' ) ||
               woo_active_sidebar( 'footer-4' ) ) && $total > 0 ) {

    ?>

    <div id="footer-widgets">
        <div class="col-full col-<?php echo $total; ?>">

        <?php $i = 0; while ( $i < $total ) { $i++; ?>
            <?php if ( woo_active_sidebar( 'footer-' . $i ) ) { ?>

        <div class="block footer-widget-<?php echo $i; ?>">
            <?php woo_sidebar( 'footer-' . $i ); ?>
        </div>

            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>

        <div class="fix"></div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /#footer-widgets  -->
    <?php } ?>
<div class="push"></div>
    <div id="footer">
        <div class="col-full">

        <div id="copyright" class="col-left">
        <?php if( isset( $woo_options['woo_footer_left'] ) && $woo_options['woo_footer_left'] == 'true' ) {

                echo stripslashes( $woo_options['woo_footer_left_text'] );

        } else { ?>
            <p><?php bloginfo(); ?> &copy; <?php echo date( 'Y' ); ?>. <?php _e( 'All Rights Reserved.', 'woothemes' ); ?></p>
        <?php } ?>
        </div>

        <div id="credit" class="col-right">
        <?php if( isset( $woo_options['woo_footer_right'] ) && $woo_options['woo_footer_right'] == 'true' ) {

            echo stripslashes( $woo_options['woo_footer_right_text'] );

        } else { ?>
            <p><?php _e( 'Powered by' ); ?> <a href="http://www.wordpress.org">WordPress</a> and <a href="http://www.woothemes.com">WooThemes. </a> <?php _e( 'Designed and edited by' ); ?> <a href="http://johns-webdesign.com/">John Brown.</a></p>
        <?php } ?>

        </div></div>
    </div><!-- /#footer  -->
</div><!-- /#wrapper -->
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
<?php woo_foot(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#footer{padding: 30px 0 20px; background: url(images/bg-ripple-footer.png) repeat top left; color:#999;}
#footer p {}
#footer a { color: #ffffff; }
#footer #credit img{vertical-align:middle;}
#footer #credit span{display:none;}

#footer-widgets { margin-bottom: -5px; background: url(images/bg-ripple-footer-widgets.png) repeat top left; padding:10px 0; height:60px; }
#footer-widgets .block { padding:20px 10px 0 10px; float:left; }
#footer-widgets .col-1 .block { width:100%; padding-left:0; }
#footer-widgets .col-2 .block { width:420px; padding-left: 20px; }
#footer-widgets .col-3 .block { width:270px; padding-left: 16px;  }
#footer-widgets .col-4 .block { width:200px; padding-left: 10px;  }
```

I hope I can get to the bottom of this with your help.
John

Comment: whenever i need a sticky footer i use the technique described on this page http://mystrd.at/modern-clean-css-sticky-footer/

Comment: I'll see if I can get it working on my wordpress theme! Thanks

Comment: Works. I'll test it on my main computer when I get a new wireless adapter (Got back from uni and forgot it...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to fix my issue by following this small tutorial:

http://mystrd.at/modern-clean-css-sticky-footer/

Credits to mfreitas for the link.

Also, regards to everyone else who helped me in this. Thanks
John

Answer (score 1):

No add this in your CSS:

```
#content {
min-height: 700px;
}
```

You need a minimum height of your content area to "push" the footer down to the bottom of the page. If the content area is a small portion inside of the wrapper, the footer will not be at the bottom of the page.

Side note: A very useful tool is using the Chrome browser. It has a built-in firebug-like extension that lets you inspect elements of a webpage while updating it at the same time.

Comment: It would work for testing on certain resolutions, but larger ones (Take eyefinity) still would have the same issue

Comment: Yes you'll need CSS Media queries would come into play. @ media only screen(max-width:768px){ #content {min-height: 700px; } } @ media only screen(min-width:768px){ #content {min-height: 900px; } } This is what many sites use these days to position according to the device and resolution of the user. You should really learn more about it, it is extremely useful.

Comment: I just want to say thanks to Kadeempardue for the information about @ media. I am currently using it on a newer version of my portfolio, and I must say - it is so bloody useful for a responsive website design!

Answer (score 0):

#### Use `position: fixed;`

Update your code with this CSS:

```
#footer {position: fixed;}
```

Comment: I've used this before but sort of went off it. I basically want it floating there.

Comment: It would be staying in the bottom, is that how do you want or... I didn't understand your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: absolute;` in your css for the footer